# Sources or sound library for fictional vocals (spoken sentences, PA)?

Tags: sound-libraries

I can find many sound websites for libraries about anything and everything non-vocal, as well as sites that focus on vocals for use in music as well as actually recorded public announcements at airports or train stations.

What I'm looking for however, are vocal soundbites like a commercial or fictional PA. For example, the famous ["a new life awaits you in the offworld colony!"](https://youtu.be/sZNzz4SaTYk?t=9) from Bladerunner, or fragments from [commercials from the fifties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUcjJ-yChjg). Or [recorded sentences](https://youtu.be/jmSPz6ffASY?t=99) used in a techno soundtrack. What about sentences, shouts, short conversations, walla in a made up language?

I basically can't find anything like that. Do libraries like that even exist? I'm looking for some spoken soundbites to complete my futuristic background design.

Comment: Hi, Benny! Just a reminder that this Sound Design forum works best when all users, both those asking the questions and answering the questions, respond with upvotes, stars for best answers, comments and further discussion. I hope that you find the answers provided so far helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects will benefit from custom recorded lines, whether spoken by you or someone you know/hire. When you do it yourself, you can customize everything from the accent to the specific type of treatment the line requires (reverb, delays, flange, etc etc).

If you don't want to use your own (or another real human's) voice, you can write out your own script and have your computer speak it for you. Even then there is so much customization available, seeing as how (at least on a Mac) you can download tons of speech packs that are specific to certain regions of the world, and even sub-sets within those regions. For example, there are two for Arabic, three for Chinese, and four for German. You can force these voices to speak English rather than their intended language, leading to even more variations on your text.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of spoken word sentences on https://sampleswap.org/index.php. Not all fictional, but it probably gives a good "base".